# How to send multiple jQuery arrays to an MVC controller?

Tags: model-view-controller

I have created  and filled **various arrays** using jquery.  First time, trying to send  JavaScript arrays to MVC controller.

Can I have an example how to do that? How can I send the arrays and other variables as well?  On the controller side, how can I retrieve the data?

Comment: -1 because you need to spend some more time in writing the question and provide more details. every server side language has it's own way of handling post data. what language are you using?

Comment: -1 for asking and asking and asking questions which are all almost the same, and handle very basic jQuery-stuff, without doing any effort to take a deeper dive in jQuery and consulting a book, tutorials, jQuery-documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can comma or pipe delimit your input and on the other end just parse it to keep things simple. Or if you want to do things the right object oriented way you could use the following code:

```
var object1 = $(".ControlArrayClass").val(); 
var object2 = $(".ControlArrayClass2").val(); 
$.post('mycontroller/myactionmethod', function( variable1: object1, variable2: object2});
```

and on the controller end it would look like this

```
public ActionResult myactionmethod(Guid[] variable1, String[] variable2)
{
//do whatever here
return View(); 
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to use [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), with a dataType parameter of 'json'.  You can send any JSON object.  Possible example:

```
var obj = {'foo': 'bar'};

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "some.aspx",
   dataType: "json",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
   data: obj,
   success: function(resp){
     alert("Response: " + resp);
   }
 });
```