# How to pass multiple jquery arrays to controller in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have tried to get an example but was noy successful so far.  I have created various arrays and filled them in jquery.  How to post all of them to the controller?  On the controller side how to retrieve them and their values? I would appreciate if I can have an example or a link with much explanation since i`m completely new to using ajax post and mvc.

What if I have other arrays as well to post over to the controller?

```
function test()
```

{ 
    var stringArray = new Array(); 
    stringArray[0] = "item1"; 
    stringArray[1] = "item2"; 
    stringArray[2] = "item3"; 
    var postData = { values: stringArray };

```
$.post("/Home/SaveList", 
postData, 
function(data){ 
    alert(data.Result); 
}, "json");
```

}

Comment: same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278853/how-to-send-multiple-jquery-arrays-to-mvc-controller

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to pass a two dimensional string array (array of array of strings) to a controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Arrays(string[][] arrays)
{
    // Do something with the arrays
    return Json(new { status = "success" });
}
```

and to post:

```
var arrays = [{'0':'value1', '1':'value2'}, 
              {'0':'value3', '1':'value4'},
              {'0':'value5', '1':'value6'}];
$.post('/home/arrays', { arrays: arrays }, function(result) {
    alert(result.status);        
});
```